# app that simulates bluetooth device (printer)

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

Is it possible to create an andorid application, that can simulate bluetooth device? I want make Android OS to think, that it is connected to the bluetooth device, which is actualy simulated by my application.

Scenario: user will install my app, and voilà, there is my virtual bluetooth device - actually, it is printer. I need it to work on non-rooted devices.

Reason: some guys are too lazy to support other bluetooth printers, so I want to simulate the supported bluetooth printer and print the data on another bluetooth printer.

FYI: I did't found, that it is not possible. I know, that emulator can not simulate it, but ShadowBluetoothAdapter from robolectric can.

Comment: Hello, did you finished this successfully? I am looking for something very similar and can't find any answer for this.

Comment: Hello Jakub, please share the link or whatever if you're successful to find the emulator tool.

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't find any working solution. I use workaround for my project. I let application to print data to PDF and then I parse this PDF.